# Como manter fixa a cor do item selecionado

Tags: android, listview

Adicionando o listener ao `Listview` através do método `setOnItemClickListener`, sempre que se clica sobre um dos seus itens, este muda momentaneamente de cor. Existe alguma forma de manter esta cor fixa no item que for clicado ?

Comment: Você está se referendo ao efeito do click? @VitorMendanha

Comment: Está a usar uma *custom view* para o item da sua lista?

Comment: Está usando `Array adapter`?

Comment: Estou a usar uma classe que extende a BaseAdapter para construir os itens da ListView. O método "setOnItemClickListener" executo-o na classe MainActivity logo a seguir ao método "setAdapter":

Comment: <code>listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lista " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
            }
        });<code/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Adicione o atributo `android:choiceMode` à *ListView*,

para permitir seleccionar apenas uma linha:

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

para permitir seleccionar mais de uma linha:

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

2 - Adicione o seguinte atributo ao *layout* do item da lista:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Se quiser *customizar* a aparência da selecção crie, na pasta *res/drawable*, um *selector* para o efeito:

***listselector.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

Altere as cores ao seu gosto!

O atributo *background* do item da lista deverá ser declarado assim:

```
android:background="@drawable/listselector"
```

---

**EDIT após comentários**

Como está a utilizar mais de uma cor para o *backgroud* das linhas da ListView, é necessário definir um *Selector* para cada uma delas:

Para atribuir a cor de fundo por defeito é criado no *Selector* um item sem *"State"*, este item tem de ser o último do *Selector*:

***listselector_par.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_purple" android:state_activated="true"/>

    <!-- cor do fundo quando não seleccionada (cor por defeito) -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
</selector>
```

Crie outro *Selector*, ***listselector_impar.xml***, indicado outra cor para o fundo.

No *Adapter* atribua ao *background* o respectivo *Selector* conforme a linha seja par ou ímpar.

**Nota:**
Se não gostar do efeito de animação elimine a linha:

```
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
```

ou altere o valor `config_mediumAnimTime`

Comment: ramaral, agora surgiu-me o seguinte problema: Se o click for longo através do método "setOnItemLongClickListener" a cor volta a não ficar fixa no item selecionado. Sabe a solução para este problema?

Comment: Declare uma variável assim: `final Boolean vemDoLongClick = false;`. Troque `return true` por `return false` e na linha anterior faça `vemDoLongClick = true;` no inicio do método `onItemClick()` faça o teste assim `if(vemDoLongClick){vemDoLongClick = false; return;}`

Comment: ramaral, a sua lógica funcionou perfeitamente! Mais uma vez um grande obrigado.