# Como mudar a cor de um item do ListView enquanto ele estiver sendo pressionado?

Tags: android, listview

Por padrão, quando você clica em um item, ele muda de cor no momento do click, porém eu alterei meu listView e este click não está funcionando. Alguém sabe como implementá-lo se é algum método pronto da view, uma animação ou alguma verificação com um setBackground? Eu testei fazer uma verificação mas não funcionou como deveria. Agradeço desde já.

Eu preciso de algo como nesta imagem, mas quando o usuário soltar o item voltar a cor normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você fala que alterou a ListView, poste esse código.

Comment: eu apenas mudei de cor alguns itens com o getview.

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73981/2541)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mudar de cor um item da listView enquanto o onItemLongClick estiver sendo chamado?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92273/como-mudar-de-cor-um-item-da-listview-enquanto-o-onitemlongclick-estiver-sendo-c)

Answer (score 2):

Crie um selector para sua lista, com as cores desejadas para clicks, longClicks, etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Depois, chame o seu seletor dentro do seu ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/meuSeletor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, tudo bem ?

Segue link da documentação oficial do Google a respeito desta funcionalidade. Ele explica bem o que cada atributo faz e dá um exemplo no final. Segue alguns trechos da página:

Crie o arquivo res/color/button_text.xml com o conteúdo abaixo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

E aqui um exemplo de implementação, note que no atributo `android:textColor` fazemos referência ao `res/color/button_text.xml` que fizemos acima:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_text"
android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

Link da página da documentação [aqui.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)