# Como continuar selecionando depois do onItemLongClick?

Tags: android

Tenho uma `listView`,que tem um método `onItemLongClick` que ao clicar seleciona o item clicado. Gostaria de saber como continuar selecionando com apenas um click.

Se alguém puder postar algum exemplo eu agradeço.

Comment: O que vc já tem feito?

Comment: tenho a lista e o método do onItemLongClick implementado, nesse método ele seleciona o item

Comment: poste o que vc tem, e onde esta o problema.

Comment: É muito código, gostaria de apenas um exemplo

Comment: É importante você postar o que você fez que está gerando a dificuldade, sugiro que dê uma lida em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se já consegue fazer a selecção então:

- Faça o método `onItemLongClick()` retornar `false`.
- Implemente o método `onItemClick()` passando o código que está no `onItemLongClick()` e que faz a selecção para ele.

Se não veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73981/2541).

Comment: Uma dica também, caso já tenho algo implementado no onItemClick(), basta utilizar um if com Boolean que também resolve.

Comment: Sim, é o que eu digo em um dos comentários da resposta que indiquei

Comment: Muito Bom, Obrigado, :)