# Android ListView - selecão/deselecão de item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Eu tenho uma aplicação que possui um ListView customizado. Ao clicar em um item desse ListView, a cor de fundo muda para indicar que ele está selecionado.

Na mesma activity eu tenho também um EditText. O problema é que quando eu "clico" no EditText a seleção do item no ListView é desfeita, ou seja, o item volta a ter a cor de fundo original. Eu não quero que isso aconteça.

Este é o código do seletor que eu uso para fazer a mudança da cor de fundo do item (list_item_selector.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_focused"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_list_normal"/>
</selector>
```

No layout do item eu defino o background do item como sendo o arquivo list_item_selector.xml (item_lista_pedido.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_all_magim"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector">

...... o resto do código

</LinearLayout>
```

Por fim, essa a a implementação do onItemClick():

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // salva a posicao do item selecionado
    lastPositionSelected = position;
    // salva o objeto relativo ao item selecionado
    servicoSelected = servicos.get(position);
    view.setSelected(true);
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como evitar que a seleção do item seja desfeita (cor de fundo volte a cor original) quando o EditText é acionado?

Comment: tenta chamar o adapter.notifyDataChanged();

Comment: ramaral Não, não é uma duplicata. São problemas diferentes. Leia novamente, o meu problema é que quando aciono o EditText a seleção do item no ListView é desfeita. Como evitar que isso aconteça?

Comment: Carlos Bridi, não entendi sua sugestão.

Comment: Elimine a linha `view.setSelected(true);` e faça o que é dito na [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73981/2541) que mencionei.

Comment: Eu estava usando o atributo "state_focused" ao invés do atributo "state_activated". Agora está funcionando, obrigado!