# Seleção e deseleção de itens em uma ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma listview que estende um baseadapter.
E seguindo a dica deste [tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73918/listview-como-manter-fixa-a-cor-do-item-selecionado) com a resposta do @ramaral eu consegui fazer com que o item selecione e deselecione mas agora como que eu faço pra verificar se o item está selecionado?

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            if (view.isSelected()){
                Toast.makeText(lista.getContext(),"SELECIONADO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(lista.getContext(),"NÃO SELECIONADO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



        }
    });
```

Com este código ele só está exibindo : "NÃO SELECIONADO"
Independendo se o item está selecionado ou não.
Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manter a cor do item listview ao pressioná-lo, inclua a seguinte linha no seu layout listview:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
```

Em seguida, defina bg_key.xml na pasta drawable como este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Finalmente, incluir isto em seu OnClickListener listview:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        ... //Anything
    }
});
```

Desta forma, somente um item será cor-selecionados a qualquer momento. Você pode definir seus valores de cor em res/values/colors.xml com algo parecido com isto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
    <color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Deu certo, vlw!